# Regex to parse polynom as monom

Tags: javascript, regex, algebra

I'm trying to parse a polynom, for example:

```
16-3x^25-6-483*x+7+5*x+8-x-15
```

Actually, I have this regex:

```
([+-]?[0-9]*?\*?x(\^[0-9]+)?)
```

Which will return:

```
-3x^25
-483*x
+5*x
-x
```

This gives me all the parts with a coefficient (number) and a litteral parts.

But I can't find a way to get the numbers without litteral parts:

```
16
-6
+7
+8
-15
```

I could use simply the split method:

```
str.split(/[+-]/)
```

to get all the monoms but this way, I'm loosing the sign in front of the numbers.

Another try is using this regex:

```
([+-]?(\d+)?\*?x?)
```

This returns all the  parts I need (with the signs), except I can't manage the 'power' sign x^25 in this example.

Comment: parseFloat(String) will get you the number with the correct sign.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/gG0tA8/1  ?

Comment: @Enissay: the regular expression get all the coefficient. This is good, except that I have then to know the litteral parts corresponding.

Comment: @nick: it give the first number. Not the following numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a "literal part" optional with:

```
(?=.+)([+-]?[0-9]*(?:\*?x(?:\^[0-9]+)?)?)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uG8dO1/3)

EDIT:
Replacing `[0-9]*` with `[0-9]+` was a mistake, without `*` regex will not match only literal elements, as you pointed out. So I changed it back, and added `(?=.+)` to avoid matching empty spaces.

Comment: Nearly everything is fetched. Except -x (or +x).

Comment: it works perfect. Thanks! Just a typo: chenged should be changed ( I can't edit just this one - it asks to change at least 6 letters).